# Changing the orientation of only some sub views in Android

Tags: android, android-sensors, android-orientation, landscape-portrait, textureview

I have a `Fragment`, on which I lock orientation to portrait when calling `onResume()` in this way:

```
if (screenOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
     getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
      }
```

Now this fragment has a view - let us call it `fragmentView`. This `fragmentView` is comprised of some other views (like `Buttons`, `TextViews`, `TextureView`, etc.)

Since the snippet in `onResume()` locks the orientation, the views do not change with the device's orientation. But, what I want is to lock the orientation selectively; i.e., when the orientation changes, I want the `Buttons` and some other `Views` to rotate accordingly, while the `TextureView` remains static.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you been able to find a solution to this? I am trying to achieve something similar myself.